# Creating new project with template not renaming to sourceName

Tags: .net-6.0

I've created a new Template for a .NET 6 project, and I'm trying to make sure it renames the project and solution file on creation. I have the following in my template.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "Jake Ford",
  "classifications": [ "FordWareMVC", "FordWareMVC", "C#" ],
  "identity": "FordWareTemplates.MVC",
  "name": "FordWare MVC Template",
  "shortName": "fordwaremvc",
  "sourceName": "_fordwaremvc",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "project"
  }
}
```

and I am running the following command, using -n to set the source name and -o to set the folder directory for the new project:

```
dotnet new fordwaremvc -n NewProjectName -o NewProjectName
```

It creates the project, but the template/solution name is not "NewProjectName", it just uses the name of the original template project...

Am I doing something wrong with the sourceName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the following:

**sourceName**: This is the value in your project/solution that will get replaced with the user-provided value in the -o parameter. **Make sure this matches the name you chose when creating your template project / solution**. The value above matches my project / solution name if you look at the template repo.

From here: https://knowyourtoolset.com/2021/08/creating-useful-net-templates/

The sourceName apparently needs to match the original solution/project name. I edited my template.json to this, and uninstalled/re-installed the template again and the original command worked:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
  "author": "Jake Ford",
  "classifications": [ "FordWareMVC", "FordWareMVC", "C#" ],
  "identity": "FordWareTemplates.MVC",
  "name": "FordWare MVC Template",
  "shortName": "fordwaremvc",
  "sourceName": "FordWare_Template",
  "tags": {
    "language": "C#",
    "type": "project"
  }
}
```